# Detecting user signing off from a background worker when hosted in a Windows Service (.NET 7)

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I have a background worker service written in .NET 7 that needs to detect when a user sign off from Windows 10. I have tried using a worker background service to detect the session events.

It works fine when hosting the worker service in a console application, but when I host it in a Windows Service the events do not trigger.

I suspect the issue has to do with the worker service missing a parameter similar to `ServiceBase.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent`

My end objective is for the Windows Service to detect when a user logs off. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += OnSessionSwitch;

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        private void OnSessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("OnSessionSwitch event");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Services run in a separate session from the user, so not surprising. Why do you need this information, you shouldn't really be interacting with the user from a service anyway? If you need to then you need a separate process that runs in the user session that communicates with the service using IPC such as a named pipe. Also from the notes on `SystemEvents` *In a Windows service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been started manually, this event will not be raised.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch#remarks

Comment: You'll need to create your own type derived from `WindowsServiceLifetime` and use that as your host lifetime. Note that the `SystemEvents` event won't be raised; it's `ServiceBase.OnSessionChange` instead.

Comment: The reason for needing to know the logged in user and when the user is logged out is because the Windows Service is connected to a server via SignalR. The connection requires the username and domain to be able to connect and also track the user.

Comment: @Charlieface I will investigate your named pipe suggestion. The service already communicates with a user process over named pipes. I guess I could have a notification from the user process when it detects the user is logging out.

Comment: Again: services run in their own session under the SYSTEM (or other) user, and multiple regular users can be logged in at once (eg on the Console or via RDP or disconnected sessions), so which username would you wish to connect with? You need to think about how you would identify a user, and whether to use a separate process than runs under the user session.